# Apache directory root and public directory can't access to files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my /var/www/ i have:

```
my_project
    |-app
       |-controllers
       |-models
       |-views
       |-core
    |-css
    |-js
    |-public
        |-index.php
```

I have set up "DirectoryRoot" to:

```
/var/www/my_project/public/
```

Now when i open web page in browser my views are loaded but links to files in css and js folders don't work. It looks like I can't go one directory up. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You can't access files outside your `DocumentRoot`

Comment: so i should move my js and css folder inside public - that make sense now - thanks